# I have questions about inotify_add_watch that read events

Tags: c, linux, api, inotify

I don't understand the progress of inotify events.
I know that inotify_init is to create new inotify instatance. and it returns file descriptor.
at this time. for what is file descriptor about?

In my code, the function, inotify_add_watch like below

```
wd = inotify_add_watch ( inotifyFd, argv[j], IN_ALL_EVENTS),
```

is called in for the loop.

If I input 2 more files in command, this loop will be repeated 2 times more. and then variable wd will be OVERWRITED. and intofiyFd always has same number. becuase these are not array.
then, How can it differentiate 2 more files?

I already learned about

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

  int inotifyFd, wd, j;
  char buf[BUF_LEN];
  ssize_t numRead;
  char *p;
  struct inotify_event *event;

  inotifyFd = inotify_init();

  for(j = 1; j < argc; j++)
  {
      wd = inotify_add_watch(inotifyFd, argv[j], IN_ALL_EVENTS);
      printf("Watching %s using wd %d\n", argv[j],  wd);
  }

  for(;;)
  {
      numRead = read(inotifyFd, buf, BUF_LEN);
      if(numRead == 0)
          fatal("read() from inotify fd returned 0!");

      printf("Read %ld bytes from inotify fd\n", (long) numRead);

      for( p = buf; p < buf+numRead; )
      {
          event = (struct  inotify_event *) p;
          displayInotifyEvent(event);

          p+= sizeof(struct inotify_event) + event->len;
      }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

.

```
./demoinotify dir1 dir2 &
[1] 5386
Watching dir1 using wd1
watching dir2 using wd2
```

Comment: The last file descriptor is removed and new one is returned. I don't understand. Inotify stores all information it needs in the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

> `inotify_init()` is to create new inotify instatance. and it returns file descriptor. at this time. for what is file descriptor about?

It returns an special file descriptor, which does not refer to any real file in the file system. Just like `pipe()`, `epoll_create()`, etc. You use that file to read *inotify events* from it. It's also pollable.

> `wd = inotify_add_watch ( inotifyFd, argv[j], IN_ALL_EVENTS)`,
>   is called in for the loop.
>   If I input 2 more files in command, this loop will be repeated 2 times more. and then variable wd will be OVERWRITED.

Don't overwrite it then. Save its return values into an array.

```
int *wd = calloc(argc, sizeof *wd);
...
wd[j] = inotify_add_watch(inotifyFd, argv[j], ...);
```

Notice that the return value of `inotify_add_watch` is not a file descriptor, but a *watch* descriptor [1].

> How can it differentiate 2 more files?

Compare the `wd` field from `inotify_event` you read from the inotify file descriptor with the return value of `inotify_add_watch` you saved above.

[1] If you look into the `/proc/PID/fdinfo/FD`, where `FD` is your `inotifyFd`, you'll see all the watch descriptors associated with it listed. The format is documented in the `proc(5)` manpage.

Comment: Or just use a VLA for `wd[argc]`.